# console.log is undefined for IE6. Is not available?

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to test my html page and make sure it works in IE6

when i given the html page developed for IE11. it throws error on IE6

On debug noticed throws error on console.log

Is console.log exist in IE6?

how to verify? any online simulator

thanks